# Как правильно сформировать запрос ajax

Tags: ajax

Имеется запрос "живого поиска", но также необходимо добавить в него выбранную радиокнопку. Реализовав таким образом, он отправляет значение выбранного переключателя только при изменении общего запроса, то есть изменении поля поиска.

Как сделать, чтобы при изменении переключателя он моментально отправлял значение в файл, без нужны изменять поле поиска после каждого изменения кнопки?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query) {
        var view = $("input[name='view']:checked").val();
        $("div#spinner").show();
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query, view:view},
            success:function(data){
                $("div#spinner").hide();
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != ''){
            load_data(search);
        }else{
            load_data();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  load_data();

  function load_data(query) {
    var view = $("input[name='view']:checked").val();
    $("div#spinner").show();
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch.php",
      method: "post",
      data: {
        query: query,
        view: view
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("div#spinner").hide();
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    if (search != '') {
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      load_data();
    }
  });
  
  $("input[name='view']").change(function() {
    if ($('#search_text').val() != '') {
      load_data($('#search_text').val());
    } else {
      load_data();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```